# Does AWS Aurora include support for the MySQL Plugin API?

Tags: mysql, aws-aurora

Amazon Aurora is marketed as a *"MySQL and PostgreSQL-compatible relational database built for the cloud"*.

Does AWS Aurora include support for the [MySQL Plugin API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/plugin-api.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a plugin on a MySQL server, you must physically upload a compiled library to the host where the MySQL server runs.

Aurora gives you no access to the host where the server runs, so there's no way you can upload code to be a plugin.

The [Amazon Aurora FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/) include this statement:

> The Amazon Aurora database engine is designed to be wire-compatible with MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 using the InnoDB storage engine.

"Wire-compatible" means a client for MySQL can connect to Aurora using the same protocol, and expect to run SQL statements that MySQL supports (mostly, but there are exceptions where some syntax does not work).

But Aurora is not compatible with MySQL with respect to server configuration or administration. Many features of MySQL Server are disabled or inaccessible.